# Power Against Specific Alternative when testing the mean of a MVN distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-normal-distribution

Consider testing a null hypothesis about the mean of a p-dimensional MVN distribution (with known covariance matrix $\Sigma$) where the form of the null is that the mean is equal to a certain vector, call it $\mu_0$.  But I am only interested in testing against alternatives coming from a certain direction, i.e. alternatives like $\mu = \mu_0 + b*h$ where $h$ is a known p-vector $b$ is an unknown scalar.

So I'm not interested in UMP tests, just tests that are most powerful against alternatives of this form.

This is a theory question -- part of a larger theory project I'm working on.  All the literature and textbooks seem to focus on UMP tests so I'm not sure where to look for this kind of thing.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to test $H_0: h^\prime\mu=h^\prime\mu_0$ against the alternative $H_A:h^\prime\mu\ne h^\prime\mu_0.$  That's the textbook univariate situation.  All you have to do is reduce the multivariate data $(X_i)$ to a univariate dataset $(h^\prime X_i)$ and you model these data as Normal with known variance $\sigma^2=h^\prime\Sigma h.$  Am I missing something here?

Comment: I've been thinking about it more and I believe you are correct.  Thanks!